# Terraform cycle error using count with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-api-gateway

I am getting Cycle errors when adding dependencies on the previous count index

I want to define an API path `/test1/{id}` using AWS Terraform with the `id` resource depending on the `test1`. If the resource is test1, the set the parent as the root API gateway resource.

```
locals {
  resources = ["test1", "{id}"]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "root_api" {
  name = "dev-api"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "dev_gateway_test_resources" {
  count       = length(local.resources)
  path_part   = local.resources[count.index]
  parent_id   = count.index == 0 ? aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.root_resource_id : aws_api_gateway_resource.dev_gateway_test_resources[count.index - 1].id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.id
}
```

The response:

```
Error: Cycle: aws_api_gateway_resource.dev_gateway_test_resources[1], aws_api_gateway_resource.dev_gateway_test_resources[0]
```

I have tried the same logic using `for_each` however I still see the same error

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a resource which is referencing itself. As of today, this is not supported in Terraform, even if it can be easily seen that the resource does not actually has a reference to itself, but to another resource of the same type created in a loop. There is an issue for supporting self referencing: [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3267)

Now, I don't know how many item can have your `resources` list, but in this case you would probably want to duplicate your `aws_api_gateway_resource`:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "dev_gateway_test_root" {
  path_part   = "test"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.root_resource_id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "dev_gateway_test_resources" {
  path_part   = "{id}"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.dev_gateway_test_root.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.id
}
```

What you want to achieve is to have an endpoint such as `/test/{id}`. From my experience API gateway endpoints tend to grow in width, meaning that you will have something like:

```
/
 /test1
    /{id}
 /test2
    /{id}
 /test3
 ...
 /testN
```

Instead of having a really lengthy endpoint, like `/test/child1/child2/.../{id}`.

You can have a loop for each level in the tree, they wont have self-referencing. You can not really have a loop between different levels of the tree.